# GitKraken does not start anymore on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: permissions, configuration

When I turned on my Ubuntu 18.04 yesterday and wanted to start GitKraken, it did not work. After I click its icon I see how the process tries to start in the upper left corner (next to "Activities") but after a few seconds the process seems to die and nothing happens.
Trying to launch GitKraken from the console fails too with the following two messages:

```
/snap/gitkraken/58/bin/desktop-launch: line 23: $HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
ln: failed to create symbolic link '$HOME/snap/gitkraken/58/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini': File exists
```

Unfortunately, my Linux skills are too limited to solve this. The only thing I've tried is `chmod 777 $HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs` because of the `Permossion denied` but that did not help.

EDIT: as terdon suggested in his comment I've made `ls -ld ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and this is its output:

`-rwxrwxrwx 1 myusername myusername 633 Mai  6 10:30 /home/mayusername/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

Then, I made the `mv ~/snap/gitkraken/58/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini gtkfilechooser.ini.bak` command and tried to start GitKraken afterwards. I did not start showing again:

`/snap/gitkraken/58/bin/desktop-launch: line 23: /home/myusername/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied`

The `ln: failed to create symbolic link ...` error from my initial post did not appear. Exe cuting `ll` in the directory `~/snap/gitkraken/58/.config/gtk-2.0` gives me the following output:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 myusername myusername 4096 Jun  3 16:44 ./
drwxrwxr-x 8 myusername myusername 4096 Mai 21 12:28 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myusername myusername   47 Jun  3 15:45 gtkfilechooser.ini -> /home/myusername/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername myusername  198 Jun  3 16:44 gtkfilechooser.ini.bak
```

`gtkfilechooser.ini -> /home/myusername/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini` is red since the file does not exist anymore. Executing the `chmod` command afterwards did not change anything. GitKraken does not start and outputs the same errors.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the output of `ls -ld ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. Also, try running `mv ~/snap/gitkraken/58/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini gtkfilechooser.ini.bak` and launching again. Finally, tell us if running the chmod command made any difference.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

SOLVED:
Had to install libgnome-keyring:
`sudo apt install libgnome-keyring0`

The UI now comes up and works for me.
Still get the following warnings, but it's working:

```
Gtk-Message: 11:19:31.343: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: 11:19:31.349: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Node started time: 1528391971495
state:  update-not-available
EVENT: Main process loaded at 441 ms
state:  checking-for-update
state:  update-not-available
state:  checking-for-update
state:  update-not-available
EVENT: Starting initial render of foreground window at 5331 ms
EVENT: Startup triggers started at 5446 ms
```

Comment: Yeap. `sudo apt install libgnome-keyring0` worked for me too in Linux Mint 19.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 19.10 I cannot run it after snap installation, so I removed Gitkraken from **snap** and then installed it after downloading from this site

https://www.gitkraken.com/download/linux-deb

Comment: Using the RPM instead of the Snap package worked for me on RHEL. The Snap application was always stuck on the splash screen. See https://support.gitkraken.com/how-to-install/#linux-deb-rpm-and-targz-files for installation instructions.